# Solitaire Game using tads(stack, Queue, Deque, List ) in Java - Classe implemented by Stack

Tags: java

I've already started work on drafting Game Solitario with tads and patterns of software in Java and I already started to make the Stack interface

```
public interface Stack <E> {

// number of elements in the stack
     public int size ();

// does not contain elements?
     public boolean isEmpty ();

// returns next object to come out without removing
     public E peek () throws EmptyStackException;

// add new stack element
      public void push (E elem) throws FullStackException;

// pops or drop next element
     public E pop () throws EmptyStackException;

}
```

and here I have a calsss LotOfCard has a collection of cards and have the LIFO behavior and you can check if a lot of cards is empty, put or add new cards in the lot and removing cards from the stack.

```
public class LotOfCards implements Stack <Card> {
     //
     private HashSet <Card> cards;//contains collections of Card

     //
     public LotOfCards() {
         this.cards= new HashSet <> ();
     }

     //
     public HashSet <Card> getCards () {
         return cards;
     }

     //
     public void setCards (HashSet <Card> cards) {
         this.cards= cards;
     }

     // return number of elements in the stack
     Override
     public int size() {
         return this.cards.size();
     }

     // does not contain elements?
     Override
     public boolean isEmpty () {
         return (this.cards.isEmpty () || this.cards == null) ;
     }

     // add new stack element
     Override
     public void push (Card element) throws FullStackException{
         this.cards.add (element);
     }

     // returns next object to come out without removing
     Override
     public Card peek () throws EmptyStackException{//Doubt here
         if (this.isEmpty ()) {
             throw new EmptyStackException ();
         }
         return (Card) null;
     }


     // pops or drop element
     Override
     Public Card pop () throws EmptyStackException{//Doubt here

         if (this.isEmpty ()) {
             throw new EmptyStackException ();
         }
         // returns the first letter is removed
         Card card = this.peek();

         // after the card is removed
         this.cards.remove (card); // Doubt

         // return card
         return card;

     }
```

and I doubt the class LotOfCard in methods peek() and pop(), ie, the method peek () returns the top object () and the method pop () since I've been deleting a chart object within the collection of cards and I have no idea how to do, thanked some explanation about creating the algorithm to develop these methods

Comment: A set has no order. If you want to order cards, don't use a set for that.

Comment: @mvw no, I don´t wanna to you write the code to implements peek() and pop(), I just wanna know, how to made the algorithm, you can explain me in your word not to you made me the code, the code I do

Comment: @immibis, the classe LotOfCards has a collection of cards, and I think to use HashSet or ArrayList, iám right?

Comment: A HashSet does not record the order in which you insert elements. An array would by fine to implement a stack data structure.

Comment: but the classe LotOfCards has a collection of cards

Comment: this case, to use array the classe LotOfCard would be static stack, right?

Answer (score 0):

@mvw, maybe you have right about An array would by fine to implement a stack data structure
and I made and test this class LotOfCards and it´s fine and this is my answer to this question

```
public class LotOfCards<Card> implements Stack<Card> {

        private Card[] array;
        private int top;
        private int capacity;//52 cards

        //
        public LotOfCards(int capacity) {
            if (capacity<= 0) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("The maximum stack size must be greater than 0.\n\n");
            } else if (capacity> 52) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("The maximum stack size should not be greater than 52.\n\n");
            }
            this.capacity = capacity;
            this.array= (Card[]) new Object[capacity];
            this.top = -1; // = 0
        }

        //return size of element in stack
        @Override
        public int size() {
            return (this.top + 1);
        }

        //stack is empty?
        @Override
        public boolean isEmpty() {
            return (this.top == -1);//==0
        }

        //stack is full
        public boolean isFull() {
            return this.capacity == this.size();
        }

        //add or push the new element in stack
        @Override
        public void push(Card element) throws FullStackException {
            if (isFull()) {
                throw new FullStackException();
            }
            this.array[++top] = element;
        }

        //return the first element, without pop or drop
        @Override
        public Card peek() throws EmptyStackException {
            if (this.isEmpty()) {
                throw new EmptyStackException();
            }
            return (Card) this.array[this.top];
        }

        //pop or drop the element on the top
        @Override
        public Card pop() throws EmptyStackException {
            //se for vazio
            if (this.isEmpty()) {
                throw new EmptyStackException();
            }
            return (Card) this.array[top--];

        }

        //for teste
        public void invertStack() throws FullStackException {
            LotOfCards<Card> stack = new LotOfCards<>(this.capacity);
            for (int i = this.top; i >= 0; i--) {
                stack.push(this.array[i]);
            }
            this.array = stack.array;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
            for (Card element: this.array) {
                if (element != null) {
                    str.append(element);
                }
            }
            return str.toString();
        }
    }
```